# Any benefits to pass parameters into a Spark Job via --conf vs spark.driver.extraJavaOptions?

Tags: java, apache-spark

Are there any benefits to pass parameters into a Spark Job using `--conf key=value` over `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dkey:value` and `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dkey:value`?

I'm asking because the latter is *more flexible* allowing you to call `System.getProperty(..)` in **any classes** where as the former requires you to pass the `SparkConf` object around in your classes.